# Compass with rails 4 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile, compass-sass

I read that compass for rails 4 is not ready, but its work with "2.0 alpha"... I don't understand.
Has anyone solved this problem it?

my Gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem "compass-rails"  #or gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"
```

my application.css.scss //no error, rails recognize the directory

```
 @import "compass";
```

my error for my first mixin test

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /partners/dashboard
Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.
```

Comment: do you have *= require_tree inside you app.css.scss?

Comment: Yes but I erased that. I solved my problem. It was just cause a double version of Compass installed and my compass was not correctly installed. Sorry but the solution "gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"" work very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ready for Rails 4.0:

http://ready4rails4.net/gems/compass-rails

And the contributors were clear on that 9 months before Rails 4 dropped:

https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/pull/59

Answer (score 1):

I have updated from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.0 including the gem compass-rails.  I have pasted in my gem file below.
I updated as many gems as possible but a couple could not get very latest versions.
The command "bundle outdated" gives you an idea about outdated gem 
Pierre

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'

# do I need this gem for form backing objects
gem 'virtus'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "compass-rails", '~> 2.0.alpha.0'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.2.1'  # java script compression

gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'debugger'
gem 'better_errors'  # railscast 402
gem 'binding_of_caller'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
# tried this update but got errors so backed out
#    gem 'bcrypt-ruby' '~>3.1.2'

# paging, searching
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'ransack'

gem "redcarpet", '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'cancan'

gem 'simple_form'

# For drill evaluation- railscast 326
gem 'active_attr'
# For db population
gem 'seed_dump'
# longitude and latitude
gem 'geo_position'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to use `@import` in a .css file. You need to rename it to `application.css.scss`. But I prefer to import compass directly in the files where I need it. And Also I prefer to import only the parts I really need like `compass/css3` so that I don't include anything I don't really use.

If that does not help with your problem, you might need to paste in the /partners/dashboard styles to see what's in there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the .scss but it was. The probleme still exist..

Comment: @DamienRomito can you update the question pasting your application.css.scss and your parters/dashbord styles?